# How to animate a constantly flickering light in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to build an iOS app with a neon light that flickers randomly and constantly like a real one would.

I'm not totally sure how to get the animation to repeat constantly, and I'm not sure how to get it to just run automatically and forever. I put this in the viewDidLoad, but I'm not sure if that's really the best place to put it?

```
    UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 5.0, options: .repeat, animations: {
        UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 2.0, animations: {
            self.Aletter.alpha = 0.2
        }) { (_) in
            UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0.0, animations: {
                self.Aletter.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: { (_) in
                UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 2.0, animations: {
                    self.Aletter.alpha = 0.6
                }, completion: { (_) in
                    UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0.0, animations: {
                        self.Aletter.alpha = 1.0
                    }, completion: { (_) in
                        UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0.0, animations: {
                            self.Aletter.alpha = 0.6
                        }, completion: { (_) in
                            UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0.0, animations: {
                                self.Aletter.alpha = 1.0
                            }, completion: { (_) in
                                UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0.0, animations: {
                                    self.Aletter.alpha = 0.6
                                }, completion: { (_) in
                                    UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0.0, animations: {
                                        self.Aletter.alpha = 1.0
                                    }, completion: { (_) in

                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    })
```

This code will run my series of flickers, but only once. I need it to go continuously.

Comment: Use recursion, calculating a new random duration / alpha on each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Matt in the comments section, you can use something like this:

```
private func flicker() { [weak self] in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
        self?.Aletter.alpha = CGFloat.random(in: 0.1...1.0)
    }) { _ in
        // When this round of animations completes call the same method again to start the animations again with a new random value for alpha.
        self?.flicker()
    }
}
```

And just call `flicker()` in your `viewDidLoad()`. `flicker` method starts an animation with a random alpha value for `Aletter` view, and when this animation completes it calls itself again.

As a side note, use small first letters for your variables, `Aletter` should be `aletter` or maybe `aLetter` based on the context.